# Unknown Column Error Mysql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT u.uid,u.status,u.category,u.role, p.uname, p.photo, p.upos, p.city, p.state, p.country, p.services, p.slug, 
(select avg(rating) from rating where uid=u.uid) as rating 
FROM `hd-users` u 
JOIN `profile` p ON p.uid=u.uid 
WHERE u.status='1' AND u.role='C' AND rating >= 4
```

this is my SQL query I'm joining three tables and while joining I am taking the average of the 3rd table. All is working perfectly but whenever I tried to compare the avg rating value with number I'm getting the error:  **Unknown column 'rating' in 'where clause'**

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of this line:

```
AND rating >= 4
```

here, rating is generated by a aggregate function and you cannot put where clause on aggregate column name.

Use having like:

```
having rating >= 4
```

**Note:** WHERE filter the record before aggregation and HAVING works after aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

it's either `p.rating` or `u.rating`. you didn't specify here which rating you have:

```
WHERE u.status='1' AND u.role='C' AND rating >= 4 // rating here has no alias
```

Comment: Check this line: **(select avg(rating) from rating where uid=u.uid) as rating** - you cannot put having condition on an aggregate column